# linux php exec() msgget:Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, php, c, linux, message-queue

I'm trying to run a linux executable from a php script (i.e. sendMsg.php).
The executable (i.e. msgr) uses SYS V msg queue to communicate with another running process.

sendMsg.php

```
<?php
    exec('./msgr 0987654321 1234 2>&1', $output, $return_var);

    var_dump($return_var);
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

msgr.c

```
  int msqid;
  key_t key;

  if ((key = ftok("/usr/local/bin/app", 'k')) == -1) {
      perror("ftok");
      exit(1);
  }

  if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0644)) == -1) {
      perror("msgget");
      exit(1);
  }
```

When I run the script from terminal, it works fine, but when I run it from the browser (via a ajax call or otherwise), I get an error:

```
msgget: Permission denied
```

Looks like some problem with file permissions. How can I solve this?

Comment: by changing permissions perhaps?

Comment: Could you please elaborate @Dagon ? I've given executable permissions to msgr.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to refer who the owner is running the execution.
Refer to [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

The owner should be www-data, but that could only be for linux-debian/ubuntu systems.

Otherwise a sudo chown 
and sudo chmod should work for your problem

Comment: Try this from the terminal php -r "echo exec('whoami');"

Comment: php -r "echo exec('whoami');" doesn't output anything.